# How to create a button when clicked a specific cell is selected based on two conditions

Tags: excel, vba, goto

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(G8:AO110,MATCH(G4,G8:G110,0),MATCH(F4,G8:AO8,0)))
```

the above formula in excel produces a cell reference. i want to create a button when clicked the cell produced by above formula is selected.
in detail, when i put 3 in F4 and "bikash" in G4, the "insert >>>" button is clicked, the cell L15 is selected.

please help

[image]

Comment: What about `Range(Range("C12").value).Select`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH BROTHER........ YOU ARE THE BEST..... saved a lot of time.... thank you !!